# Format date output of time stamp in php

Tags: php

I'm using the following php command in displaying the time stamp in the table of my database system (postgresql) on a webpage

```
while ($column = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$column[0]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

However the time stamp format is too detailed and how could I simplify it display format for example just '2014-04-18 18:29'

The current output is something like 2014-04-18 18:07:36.978
Thank you in advance for every help.

Comment: "*However the time stamp format is too detailed*" — What exactly does it output? And did you try using `strtotime()`?

Comment: what does $column[0] shows as output ?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a timestamp such as `Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200` (or similar) you can use `date` and `strtotime`:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($column[0]));
```

Alternatively, if you use PHP 5.2+, you can use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/DateTime) class:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($column[0]);
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```